# Обработка переменной на PHP

Tags: php

Есть переменная вида:

```
$a = "a:20:{тут чета написано}";
```

Собственно интересует все, что до первой кавычки "{" приравнять к $b; все, что после - к $с; ну как содержимое кавычек, от первой открывающей до последней закрывающей, поместить в $с? Чтобы получилось

```
$b="a:20:"; $c="тут чета написано"; $d="";
```

Конечно же, можно обрезать переменную с начала и с конца, но моя проблема заключается в том, что количество знаков неизвестно.

**update**: $d = все, что останется после последней закрывающей кавычки. Там может что-то быть, а может и ничего не быть.

Comment: А что в `$d` поместить надо?

Comment: если что то останется после последней ковычки. добавлю в описание

Comment: Ступил, спасибо.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь написать свою реализацию [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize)? Зачем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = "a:20:{тут чета написано {аля кавычки} {аля кавычки 2} а тут еще чета написано";
$a = preg_replace("/^(.*?)\{{1,}(.*?)\}{0,}(.*?)$/", "$1|$2|$3", $a);
$a = explode("|", $a);

echo $b = $a[0];
echo $c = $a[1];
echo $d = $a[2];
```

**Апнул ответ!**

Comment: Если это все-таки сериализованные данные php, то там может встретится что-то вроде `s:2:"{}";i:1;a:1:{i:0;i:1;}i:2;s:2:"{}"`

Answer (score 3):

```
$x = explode('{', $a);
$y = explode('}', $x[1]);

$b = $x[0];
$c = $y[0];
$d = $y[1];
```

UPD:

- Поиск первого вхождения - **strpos**
- Поиск последнего вхождения - **strrpos**

Comment: эм... уважаемый, все весело и работает, но я не случайно написал ПЕРВОЙ открывающей ковычки, т.к. внутри "тут чета написано" тоже могут быть ковычки. так что метод подходит, но не во всех случаях 8-(

Comment: @mixalef, тогда используйте поиск первого и последнего вхождений. Поправил ответ.